# Common DFS question "Connect cell" or "find island" but only find rectangular shape

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, data-structures, depth-first-search

I've just learned an algorithm called DFS and when I watched the videos, the most popular practice or example to use DFS is the Connected Cells or find islands one which is a 2D array with 0 and 1. But I really wish to know if I want the island shape only to be rectangular(or square), what should I do or how can I change the if or for loop in the program. Here's the code I'm looking at:

```
    // No. of rows and columns 
    static final int ROW = 3, COL = 5; 

    // A function to check if a given cell (row, col) can 
    // be included in DFS 
    boolean isSafe(int M[][], int row, int col, 
                boolean visited[][]) 
    { 
        // row number is in range, column number is in range 
        // and value is 1 and not yet visited 
        return (row >= 0) && (row < ROW) && (col >= 0) && (col < COL) && (M[row][col] == 1 && !visited[row][col]); 
    } 

    // A utility function to do DFS for a 2D boolean matrix. 
    // It only considers the 8 neighbors as adjacent vertices 
    void DFS(int M[][], int row, int col, boolean visited[][]) 
    { 
        // These arrays are used to get row and column numbers 
        // of 8 neighbors of a given cell 
        int rowNbr[] = new int[] { -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1 }; 
        int colNbr[] = new int[] { -1, 0, 1, -1, 1, -1, 0, 1 }; 

        // Mark this cell as visited 
        visited[row][col] = true; 

        // Recur for all connected neighbours 
        for (int k = 0; k < 8; ++k) 
            if (isSafe(M, row + rowNbr[k], col + colNbr[k], visited)) 
                DFS(M, row + rowNbr[k], col + colNbr[k], visited); 
    } 

    // The main function that returns count of islands in a given 
    // boolean 2D matrix 
    int countIslands(int M[][]) 
    { 
        boolean visited[][] = new boolean[ROW][COL]; 
        int count = 0; 
        for (int i = 0; i < ROW; ++i) 
            for (int j = 0; j < COL; ++j) 
                if (M[i][j] >= 100 && !visited[i][j]) 
                { 
                    DFS(M, i, j, visited); 
                    ++count; 
                } 

        return count; 
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. To make your code [mre] please add hard coded test data (matrix) and the expected result.

Comment: By rectangular shape, did you mean cycle of 4 vertices?

Comment: @AkashDahane rectangle can have of any even number of vertices  >= 4

Comment: @c0der and what about cycle?

Comment: @AkashDahane I am not sure I understand. A rectangle is a cycle (in a graph), isn't it ?

Comment: @AkashDahane a cycle can have of any even number of vertices >= 3